# Record in database mysql with restriction

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I need to change my records in database for example:

"`player ID`" is EXACTLY 11 digits, I did the `decimal(11,0)`, but I can add there 3 or 4 digits.

Any help on this?

Comment: Why does this have to be on database level? Why not check it in your app before the ID is created?

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Well, it should be on level before adding to table, vefore creating it. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alter table tablename modify playerID decimal(20,0)
```

if you want to change to new type, try this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn newtype
```